# Why is my JSONP returning Invalid JSON

Tags: jquery, python, django, json, jsonp

I'm currently puling data from an external XML file and converting it to JSON via Python/Django. The problem I'm encountering is that when I pull the JSON in JQUERY, I'm getting the error of "Invalid JSON" however when I put my JSON through a validator such as [JSONFormatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) I am being told that my JSON is valid.

Python code:

```
def test(request):


    tree = lxml.etree.parse("http://somedomain.com")
    deals = tree.xpath("/page/deals/deal")

    deals_info = []

    for deal in deals:
        this_value = {
            "id":deal.find("id").text,
            "totaldealcount":deal.find("totaldealcount").text,
            "offer":deal.find("offer").text,
            "link":deal.find("link").text,
            "merchantname":deal.find("merchantname").text,
            "saleprice":deal.find("saleprice").text,
            "productvalue":deal.find("productvalue").text,
            }
        deals_info.append(this_value)


    json_deals = '{"deals":' + simplejson.dumps(deals_info) + '}'

    if("callback" in request.GET.keys()):
        callback = request.GET["callback"]
    else:
        callback = None

    if(callback):
        response = HttpResponse("%s(%s)" % (
                callback,
                simplejson.dumps(deals_info)
                ), mimetype="application/json"
            )
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(json_deals, mimetype="application/json")
    return response
```

The returned JSON

```
    mycallback([{"productvalue": "40.00", "totaldealcount": "4", "merchantname": "Joes Door Knobs", "offer": "$40 Deal for $20", "link": "http://somelink.com", "saleprice": "20.00", "id": "3112264"}, {"productvalue": "20.00", "totaldealcount": "4", "merchantname": "Bob's Pizza", "offer": "$20 Deal for $10", "link": "http://somelink.com", "saleprice": "10.00", "id": "3112266"}])
```

My jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.urltomydomain.com?callback=mycallback",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(x,y,z) {
    // x.responseText should have what's wrong
        console.log(x)
        console.log(y)
        console.log(z)
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell jQuery that this is JSONP (which is actually just a script.  It's a call to a function with your JSON data), not JSON data itself.  It said 'invalid JSON' because jQuery was trying to parse the function call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.urltomydomain.com",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(x,y,z) {
        // x.responseText should have what's wrong
        console.log(x)
        console.log(y)
        console.log(z)
    }
});
```

`dataType: "jsonp"` automatically adds the `?callback=?` to your url, so its not needed here.

You can also use `getJSON` (which requires you to add `?callback=?`).

```
$.getJSON('http://www.urltomydomain.com?callback=?', function(json){
    console.log('success');
    console.log(json);
});
```

You should use `?callback=?` because jQuery will automatially replace the second `?` with a dynamic name for the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of JSONP is that you aren't returning JSON, you're returning *JavaScript that the browser can execute*.

Instead of using jQuery's AJAX function (and instead of incorrectly telling it to expect a `dataType` of `json`) you can just add a new `<script>` to the page:

```
$.getScript('http://www.urltomydomain.com?callback=mycallback');
```

Comment: I changed to `$.getScript('http://www.urltomydomain.com?callback=mycallback', function(data, textStatus){
   console.log(data); //data returned
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log('Load was performed.');
});` and am getting `undefined` for my data

Comment: @bigmike What about your `mycallback` function? Is the JSON being correctly sent to it?